# Changing the height attribute of svg tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

I am trying to change the height attribute of all SVG tags on my html page using Java Script when viewed using Firefox. I firstly check if the browser is FF, then I get the current height of the svg and then add 30 to it.

The script I have written doesn't work:

```
var FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (FIREFOX) {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getAttribute('height'); 
  var svgHeight = x + 30;
  document.getElementsByTagName('svg').setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
}
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).getAttribute is not a function

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 300;" class="ct-chart-bar" height="300" width="100%">
```

to

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 300;" class="ct-chart-bar" height="330" width="100%">
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: height is a string so if height is 12 then height + 30 would be 1230. To answer your question though you need to break it down. What is document.getElementsByTagName('svg') returning? What is the first item in that list? etc.

Comment: As i proven in my answer, you need to either remove the inline style when setting height attribute or set the style height to make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The getAttribute() method will return a string. You need to convert the string to a number. This was pointed out by Robert Longson.

The line calling setAttribute() method in missing the indexer. Your code was calling setAttribute() on the collection instead of on the individual element.

One solution is to change your code from...

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getAttribute('height'); 
var svgHeight = x + 30;
document.getElementsByTagName('svg').setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
```

to...

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getAttribute('height'); 
var svgHeight = parseFloat(x) + 30;
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
```

Comment: The question originally only mentioned height attribute. The question was later edited to include the HTML code showing both height attribute and height style. I read and answered the original question. My answer worked for the original question. I did not notice that the question had been edited between the time I read it and the time I posted my answer.

Comment: FYI your answer came 19 minutes _after_ the second edit (and at the exact time as my answer), nevertheless, the OP make the choice he wants, and you are allowed :) to update yours with a note about the inline precedence.

Answer (score 1):

As the height value returned is a string, you first need to change to this:

```
var svgHeight = parseInt(x) + 30;
```

Second, the 3 sample shows that the inline style has precedence over the attribute so you should change that instead of the height attribute if both is present on the element.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.height; 
var svgHeight = parseInt(x) + 30;
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.height = svgHeight + 'px';


/* This doesn't work as the inline style has precedence */
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[1].getAttribute('height'); 
var svgHeight = parseInt(x) + 30;
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[1].setAttribute('height', svgHeight);


var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[2].getAttribute('height'); 
var svgHeight = parseInt(x) + 30;
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[2].setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
```

```html
<svg style="width: 30%; height: 100px;" height="100" width="30%">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill:green"></rect>
</svg>

<svg style="width: 30%; height: 100px;" height="100" width="30%">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill:red"></rect>
</svg>

<svg height="100" width="30%">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill:blue"></rect>
</svg>
```